Vector bundle over $S^n$ is isomorphic to that induced by a small transition data.
Definition: Small transition data:On $M$ with values in $GL_r$ is an open cover consisting of 2 elements: $\{U_1, U_2\}$ of $M$ together with a smooth map
$$ \tau = \tau_{1,2} : U_1 \cap U_2 \to GL_r, $$, where $GL_r$ invertible matrices of rank r with real entries.
(then $\tau_{2,1} = \tau_{1,2}^{-1}, \tau_{1,1} = \tau_{2,2} = \mathrm{Id}$).
I am working on:
Assuming you know that any vector bundle over a contractible manifold is trivializable
Show that any vector bundle over a sphere $S^n$ is isomorphic to one that is induced by a small transition data.
I am having trouble with this I am not sure if I am using " that any vector bundle over a contractible manifold is trivializable" where I am supposed to use it and if the isomorphism is the righ one?  I have tried the following, but it does not use the construction at the end of the post that defines E as a quotient starting with small data, that I thought I had use.
I would appreciate you'd give me feedback on my attempt and if it is wrong/incomplete, help me fix it or complete it. Additionaly how should I use the quotient definition of $E$ as an alternative proof if mine works as it is?
Define the open cover of $S^n$ as:
$$
  U_1 = \{ x \in S^n : x_n > -\epsilon \}, \quad U_2 = \{ x \in S^n : x_n < \epsilon \},
  $$
for some small $\epsilon > 0$. The overlap $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a "band" around the equator, where $|x_n| < \epsilon$.
Over each open set $U_1$ and $U_2$, the vector bundle is trivializable. This is where we use the fact that any vector bundle over a contractible manifold is trivializable:

Each open set $U_1$ and $U_2$ is contractible (since they are homeomorphic to open disks in $\mathbb{R}^n$).
Therefore, the vector bundle is trivial over each of $U_1$ and $U_2$.

To construct an isomorphism between $E$ and a vector bundle determined by small transition data:

Over $U_1$ and $U_2$, since the vector bundle is trivial, we can write:
$$
   E|_{U_1} \cong U_1 \times \mathbb{R}^r, \quad E|_{U_2} \cong U_2 \times \mathbb{R}^r.
   $$
Let $e_1^\alpha, e_2^\alpha, \dots, e_r^\alpha$ be the standard basis for the trivial bundle over $U_\alpha$ for $\alpha = 1, 2$.

The transition function $\tau_{12}: U_1 \cap U_2 \to GL_r$ defines how the bases over $U_1$ and $U_2$ are related:
$$
   e_i^2 = \sum_j \tau_{12}^{ij}(x) e_j^1 \quad \text{for} \quad x \in U_1 \cap U_2.
   $$
This transition function completely determines the vector bundle, as it encodes how the trivializations over $U_1$ and $U_2$ are "glued" together.


The map that sends a section $s \in E$ to its representation in the trivial bundles over $U_1$ and $U_2$ via the transition function $\tau_{12}$ is an isomorphism:
$$
   s \mapsto (s|_{U_1}, s|_{U_2}) \quad \text{subject to} \quad s|_{U_2} = \tau_{12}(x) s|_{U_1} \text{ on } U_1 \cap U_2.
   $$
This map is well-defined, smooth, and has a smooth inverse (because the transition function $\tau_{12}$ is invertible by construction, with $\tau_{21} = \tau_{12}^{-1}$).

Definition: Transition data on (a manifold) $M$ with values in $GL_r$" consists of an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ of $M$, indexed by some set $\Lambda$. and for each $\alpha, \beta \in \Lambda$, a smooth function with values in  $GL_r$
$\tau_{\alpha,\beta}: U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to GL_r,$
such that the  "cocycle condition" is satisfied: for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Lambda$, one has:
$\tau_{\alpha,\beta} \cdot \tau_{\beta,\gamma} = \tau_{\alpha,\gamma},$
over $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \cap U_\gamma$.
This could also be useful:
Starting with a transition data $\{U_\alpha, \tau_{\alpha,\beta}\}$ on a manifold $M$ one can construct a vector bundle $E$.
Considering $S=\{(\alpha, x, v) : \alpha \in \Lambda, x \in U_\alpha, v \in \mathbb{R}^r\},$ $(\alpha, x, v) \sim (\beta, y, w) \Longleftrightarrow y = x, \, w = \tau_{\beta,\alpha}(v)$. Define then $E =S/\sim$.

What do you mean by "small transition data?"

@MoisheKohan It's the definition given in the first paragraph, because there is only one transition function and 2 elements in the cover

Ok, then what you wrote is a valid solution, except I do not see a need to prove an isomorphism since you are literally defining a trivializing atlas on your original bundle.
